# How to select a group of objects to animate in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have just placed 20 text objects onto my slide.

Is there an easy way to select them all and then choose an animation that will be ***the same for them all***?

That is, the first object animates onclick, then the second object animates onclick, and so on..

*(I do not want to place them in a group, they must animate individually animate)*

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an easy task.

Just select all the text boxes with your mouse (or `Ctr+A` inside the slide if you don't have any other elements), go to "Animations" tab and select the animation you want.

Make sure your text boxes are still selected and open the Animation Pane (you will find this in the same Animations tab). There you will find all the animations you selected for your text boxes and the last one will have a dropdown button where you can select "Start on click". This option will apply to all your text boxes.

Here is a picture with all the buttons:
[image]